# Was Yoda a Padawan or a Jedi Knight?

Tags: star-wars, jedi-training

I have come across some seemingly contradictory information while reading about Yoda's early life. The Wookieepedia entry on [Yoda](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yoda) states:

> Master Gormo took them to his home where he trained them in the ways of the Force and, not long after their training was complete, a Galactic Republic starship picked up their distress signal and rescued the two friends, who were now Jedi themselves.

Yoda's training was complete and he was already a Jedi Knight when he arrived on Coruscant, according to this entry. However, the Wookieepedia entry on [Master Gormo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/N%27Kata_Del_Gormo) states:

> After a couple of days, Master del Gormo met with the duo and informed them that they were in fact Force-sensitive; offering to train them as his Padawans.... Departing the world, Yoda would go to Coruscant where he would continue his training at the Jedi Temple, eventually ascending to the rank of Grand Master.

Here, Yoda was still a Padawan when arriving at Coruscant. He then continued his training at the Jedi Temple (even though he was a Padawan, not a Jedi Initiate) until he became a Jedi Knight, working his way up the ranks after that.

Is there any other information that can clarify whether Yoda was a Padawan or a Jedi Knight after leaving Master Gormo and arriving on Coruscant?

Comment: Where does it say he continued at the Temple as a Padawan?  He could've continued his training there as a Jedi, couldn't he?  (I mean, it's not like you stop getting better upon reaching the "Jedi Knight" rank...)

Comment: I'm going off the definition on Wookieepedia, that a Jedi Knight has completed training at the academy as a Jedi Initiate, Padawan training, and the Jedi Trials. Once you are a Knight you go on assignments for the Counsel and you official training is over.

Comment: @user1964 It says right there in your second quote that he "continued his training"..."to the rank of Grand Master".

Comment: @NominSim And it says in the first quote that his "training was complete" and was now a Jedi. And the second quote could be ambiguous in that he trained at the temple, then worked his way up to Grand Master (not necessarily implying he was training the whole time).

Answer (score 8):

There is no further information about Yoda's backstory, since Lucas is notoriously unwilling to reveal it.

That particular tidbit of info is canon, but of an unusual origin. Gormo's Wikia page states:

> N'Kata Del Gormo was created by Chuck Hamilton, a Star Wars fan, for the backstory of his Hysalrian entry in the Design an Alien contest held in the Star Wars Galaxy Magazine

---

---

Please note that these "Design an Alien" contest entries [ARE canon according to Leland Chee](http://web.archive.org/web/20070318144912/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?messageID=14866609), [the ultimate authority on SW canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Leland_Chee):

> Tasty Taste; Date Posted: May 03, 2006 05:45 PM
>
> > **Q:** *Star Wars Galaxy Magazine #7 published the winners of the "Design an Alien" contest, where fans were encouraged to submit artwork and back-stories of new SW aliens. Are these aliens canon?*
>
> **A:** Yes, though any text discrepancies with other sources would likely to superseded by the other source.

---

(Just to confuse the issue FURTHER, the original implication was that the swamp planet where Yoda was discovered was Dagobah... which of course Lucas made non-canon with RotS where it said Yoda never visited Dagobah before... BUT [as per Leland Chee](http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?messageID=14866609#14866609), the fact of Yoda's training by Gormo is **still** canon, just not on that planet).

> > **Q:** "does it follow that N'Kata Del Gormo is actually canon, since it's not directly overruled by another source?"
>
> **A:** "The existence of such character is part of continuity, but his appearance on Dagobah would not be, since the time of Ep III is the first time that Yoda ever sets foot on Dagobah as noted in the Revenge of the Sith novelization."

Comment: I'm not really questioning Gormo's legitimacy as canon. If I'm reading this right, your answer to the question about Yoda's rank is that there is no further information?

Comment: @iHateShog - Correct. Basically, it kinda accidentally slipped into canon out of the left field based on their own rules that they can't deny, but Lucas' stated policy is to shroud Yoda's past in as much fog and mystery as possible; and since the source is a very isolated one (an entry in an obscure contest) there's very little chance any details will ever be fleshed out due to that policy.

Comment: Maybe Disney will rectify that. Or, at least say what species Yoda is. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The second enttry says that Yoda "Would" go to Coruscant where he would continue his Jedi training. It doesn't say though that he was or was not a Jedi at the time of his arrival on Coruscant.

It is likely that somewhere between the two entires, he continued his training and acheived the level of Jedi knight before arriving on Coruscant.

I rememeber reading that once he became a Jedi knight, he then retreated someplace, either on coruscant or perhaps to another planet.. perhaps even Dagobah, and spend 100 YEARS in meditation to totally perfect his power and control over the force. This, along with his incredibly high midi-chlorian count of 18,000, is why he was one of the most powerful Jedi Masters to have ever lived.